Python, running concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor inside another concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
I am running subdomain enumeration using different tools where I will iterate a list of domains over a list of tools. To speed up the process, I implemented multi threading using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor. In my scenario, I will have two ThreadPoolExecutor, first one is when I iterate through (lets say) 10000 domains, the second one will be when I iterate and run the 7 different command line tools(using subprocess to run the command) on one specific domain.
Inside the main.py
import enumFunctions
domains = get_domains() # a list of strings
count=0
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    for domain in domains:
        count+=1
        print(count)
        executor.submit(enumFunctions.subdomainEnum, domain[0],client)

inside enumFunctions.py is:
function_and_parameters = [
        (tool1,domain) # tool1 is a function
        (tool2,domain) # tool2 is a function
             ...
]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
    for tool,param in function_and_parameters:
        executor.submit(tool, param)

The expected output will be:
1
2
3
4
5
...
50 # stuck here for a while and waiting for worker to be freed to continue
51
52


However, what I am getting it
1

2
3
4
5
...
50 # after a few seconds/mins, the count immediately goes to 4000 something, instead of incrementing slowly.

Really appreciate if anyone could tell me where I did wrong here
Thanks in advance!
Minimum runnable codes:
main.py
import sys
import enumFunctions
# from enumeration import enumFunctions
import time
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
import logging
import concurrent.futures

offset=15000
count=0
chunck=5000
max_count=9999999
domains=[x for x in range(0,100000)]
while True:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        for domain in domains:
            count+=1
            print(count)
            executor.submit(enumFunctions.subdomainEnum, domain)
    offset+=chunck
    if offset>=max_count:
        offset = 0

enumFunctions.py
import random
import time
import concurrent.futures

def subdomainEnum(domain):
    function_and_parameters = [
        (tool1,domain),
        (tool2,domain),
        (tool3,domain),
        (tool4,domain),
        (tool5,domain)
    ]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
        for func,p1 in function_and_parameters:
            print(domain,func)
            executor.submit(func,p1)

def tool1(domain):
    time.sleep(random.randint(4,30))
    print("tool1",domain)
    return

def tool2(domain):
    time.sleep(random.randint(4,30))
    print("tool2",domain)
    return

def tool3(domain):
    time.sleep(random.randint(4,30))
    print("tool3",domain)
    return

def tool4(domain):
    time.sleep(random.randint(4,30))
    print("tool4",domain)
    return

def tool5(domain):
    time.sleep(random.randint(4,30))
    print("tool5",domain)
    return




Please extract a [mcve] and provide that in your question.

Thank you for the response, just added a working example.@UlrichEckhardt

What's the output it produces? What output would you expect? Also, it's not minimal yet, but it's much better than before already.

@UlrichEckhardt, I am expecting the while loop to wait for the with to finish. It should print the count slowly. However, in reality, it seems to finish the while loop first, then the threads start to work.

Your with block  only submits all the tasks, i.e. places them on a task queue for execution, and when you exit that block there is an implicit call to executor.shutdown(wait=True) to wait for the submitted tasks to complete. Please distinguish between submitting tasks, which get queued up for execution, and an idle thread taking the task off the queue and executing it.

@Booboo Thank you! I think your answer makes sense. with  block here will just submitting the task but not actually doing the work. As a result, it doesnt wait there for the tasks to be finished. It just keeps submitting the task. This explains why the number goes straight to 4000. After it finishes submitting everything, then the thread pool start to do the heavy lifting with 50*7 threads.

Think of this as a long comment with some coding suggestions:
In your demo code each domain is being submitted as a task to a multithreading pool of size 50 and each of those tasks is creating a new multithreading pool of size 7 (why not size 5?) and submitting to this new pool 5 tasks. So at any point in time you may have 50 + 50 * 7 = 400 threads created with potentially 50 + 50 * 5 = 300 threads executing concurrently. So why not just create a single pool of size 300, which you pass to subdomainEnum along with the domain? This will save you the unnecessary creating and terminating of multithreading pools. This, of course, does not by itself explain why the count goes immediately to 4000. But if for some reason you get to a point where subdomainEnum is unable to create new pools at least for a while, then you would see something like what you experience. You could try either catching and printing exceptions in subdomainEnum or calling method add_done_callback on all Future instances created by submit and testing for an exception that way. But you should definitely follow my suggestion and try to create a single multithreading pool of size 300. If you are unable to do that, you know you have a problem. If this is the case, all hope is not lost. You can switch to using asyncio as follows:
import asyncio

# subdomainEnum will be inline so comment out import:
# from enumFunctions import subdomainEnum

def get_domains():
    # Make this a generator expression to save storage and processing
    # and have fewer domains for testing purposes:
    #domains = [x for x in range(0, 100000)]
    domains = (x for x in range(0, 10))
    return domains

async def main():
    count = 0
    while True:
        tasks = []
        for domain in get_domains():
            count += 1
            print(count)
            task = asyncio.create_task(subdomainEnum(domain))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)

# What is in file enumeration.py

import random

async def subdomainEnum(domain):
    await asyncio.gather(
        tool1(domain),
        tool2(domain),
        tool3(domain),
        tool4(domain),
        tool5(domain)
    )

async def tool1(domain):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 30))
    print("tool1", domain)

async def tool2(domain):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 30))
    print("tool2", domain)

async def tool3(domain):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 30))
    print("tool3", domain)

async def tool4(domain):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 30))
    print("tool4", domain)

async def tool5(domain):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 30))
    print("tool5", domain)

if __name__== '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Your actual tool1 through tool5 functions will need to be modified to use asyncio as I have done. Not knowing what you are actually doing in these functions I can't say how difficult that would be for you.
